# Insert and email all the fields in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, insert

Here is my code.

I am inserting form data into a database. It is working successfully, but I also want to send form data into an email ID, so we can receive all the data in email ID too.

Please suggest what I should do; what kind of changes are needed in my code?

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "0000000";
    $password = "0000000";
    $db_name = "0000000";
    $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); // MySQL connection
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("can not select DB"); // Select database
    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile      = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email       = $_POST['email'];
    $message     = $_POST['message'];
    $rdDomestic  = $_POST['rdDomestic'];
    $fromCity    = $_POST['fromCity'];
    $toCity      = $_POST['toCity'];
    $dtDeparture = $_POST['dtDeparture'];
    $dtReturn    = $_POST['dtReturn'];
    $cmbAdult    = $_POST['cmbAdult'];
    $cmbChild    = $_POST['cmbChild'];
    $cmbChild    = $_POST['cmbChild'];
    $cmbInfants  = $_POST['cmbInfants'];
    $rdClass     = $_POST['rdClass'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `insert_flight`(`F_Inq_ID`, `name`, `mobile`, `email`, `message`, `rdDomestic`, `fromCity`, `toCity`, `dtDeparture`, `dtReturn`, `cmbAdult`, `cmbChild`, `cmbInfants`, `rdClass`)

     VALUES ('', '$name', '$mobile', '$email', '$message', '$rdDomestic', '$fromCity', '$toCity', '$dtDeparture', '$dtReturn', '$cmbAdult', '$cmbChild', '$cmbInfants', '$rdClass')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . mysql_error());

    // Starting email sending data below  //
    mysql_close($con);

    $header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $subject = "New Flight Inquiry Received";
    $email_to = "0000000@gmail.com";
    $message = "Full Name: $name\n"
               . "Mobile: $mobile\n"
               . "Email: $email\n"
               . "message: $message\n"
               . "From City: $fromCity\n"
               . "To City: $toCity\n";
    mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $header);

    // End sending email data...

    if ($query) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you!!!! We received your request. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>
<?php

    }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, 0000');
            window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: check spam folder and use `mysqli` instead of mysql.

Comment: Probably your email is going to spam. If possible, you can use something on the lines of phpMailer which uses smtp authentication to send email

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$to = '0000000@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New Flight Inquiry Received';
$msg = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>User Details</title>
        <body>
            <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr><td>Full Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Mobile</td><td>' . $mobile . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>message</td><td>' . $message . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>From City</td><td>' . $fromCity . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>To City</td><td>' . $toCity . '</td></tr>
        </body>
    </html>';
$from  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$from .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$from .= 'From: info@abcd.com';
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
```

This code integrates in your page.

Comment: This does not produce well-formed HTML; both `head` and `table` are missing an end tag.